# JavaScript regex replace not working?

Tags: javascript, replace

I have this JavaScript code:

```
var test123 = $('product-price-' + productId).innerHTML; // thats 26,00&nbsp;€
var finalPrice = test123.replace(/[^\d.,]/, "");
```

Testing my regex here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html correctly returns me 26,00, exactly what I want. Why is it not working in my code? In my code it replaces nothing at all.

Thanks!

Comment: @DavidThomas That doesn't looks like jQuery. I think that it's MooTools (or any other library where `$` is a shortcut for `document.getElementById`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the period and add `g` to make it global;

```
/[^\d\.,]/g
```

Comment: Escaping the period is unnecessary inside a character class.

Comment: @verdesmarald: Exactly, the problem must be somewhere else, but the g made it work.

**Solution:** By adding the g I made it work.

Comment: @user1638055 The `g` modifier part is correct and will solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed now, too. Can you explain why please?

Comment: @user1638055 `g` is a modifier to make the regex "global". Without `g`, the regex is only applied to the first match (so in your case it matches just `&` in `26,00&nbsp;€`), with `g` it is applied to every match in the string (so it matches `&`, `n`, `b`, `s`, `p`, `;` and `€`).